# How to show random view controller on button click iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app having 7 screen and 3 tabs. on the screen 7 i have a button that submits data but after submitting data , the UI still shows screen 7
I want to show my screen 1 (of tab 1)so that user can restart next operation, screen 1  has nav bar , table view control and few other buttons.

I know in submit action of the button i have to do some calling , but no idea  exactly what to do..

Pls suggest/help. Thanks in adv.

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: yes...but i can do either way ..objective C or story board..

Comment: If my answer does not work please tell me so I can edit it.

Comment: @AbdullahShafique pls check my below comment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 NSArray *mycontrollers = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;
 NSLog(@"%@",mycontrollers);
 UINavigationController *nvc = [mycontrollers objectAtIndex:0];
 UIViewController *vc = [nvc topViewController];
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Control-drag form your button to you new viewcontroller and select Modal.

Comment: thanks but My controller heir arch is tabbarcontroller =>Navcontroller=>tableViewControler (I have to show this) . I got the exception after running the above code"Here is the log :<UINavigationController: 0x9ba4b40>",
    "<UIViewController: 0x9bb6290>",
    "<ContactViewController: 0x9bb7190>",
    "<UIViewController: 0x9bb77a0>"  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller <DeclarationViewController: 0x9977c50>.'

Comment: @Lalit_vicky What is the name of your tableviewcontrller.

Comment: @Lalit_vicky Also what tab is screen 7 in?

Comment: screen 7 is DeclarationViewController but the tableviewcontoller is not named. so its the defauls UITableviewcontroller. shall i add a class and attach to it?

Comment: @abdullah... tried your edit.. no exception code runs fine but stays on screen 7 .

Comment: @Lalit_vicky Thats weird...try attacthing a file to the tableviewcontroller

Comment: I added the ChecklistTableViewController for the table view. Is there any way to do in story board?

Comment: @Lalit_vicky Try control-dragging you button to the tableviewcontroller and select modal

Comment: @abdullah.. thanks mate it worked.. but small question here.. as i know we have root(tab controller) pushed to Navigation controller and then the table view. Now i am creating a modal directly to my root. so what about the stack tats created. willn't it cause any problem..pls share your thoughts.. again a huge thanks..

Comment: @Lalit_vicky I do not think it should cause any problems. If you have any problems be sure to ask me or post it here. Do not forget the check :)